# Recursive generator and `yield from`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data structure which is essentially a mixture of nested lists/dictionaries:

```
class System:
    def __init__(self, name, subsystems, uri):
        self.name = name
        self.subsystems = subsystems
        self.uri = uri

A = System("A", [], "http://A")
B1 = System("B1", [], "http://B/B1")
B21 = System("B12", [], "http://B/B2/B21")
B22 = System("B22", [], "http://B/B2/B22")
B2 = System("B2", [B21, B22], "http://B/B2")
B = System("B", [B1, B2], "http://B")
C1 = System("C1", [], "http://C/C1")
C = System("C", [C1], "http://C")
S = System("S", [A, B, C], None)
```

In Python I wrote the following recursive generator:

```
def find_subsystem(system, name):
    if system.name == name:
        yield system.uri
    for sub in system.subsystems:
        yield from find_subsystem(sub, name)
```

allowing me to do "queries" like

```
next(find_subsystem(S, "B22"))
#=> 'http://B/B2/B21'
```

or

```
list(find_subsystem(S, "B22"))
#=> ['http://B/B2/B21', 'http://B/B2/B22']
```

Is this the "best" (performance and/or code cleanliness) to do that?

Comment: Looks quite neat to me, but since question has no clear answer, it shall be close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if it's closed for that reason, but I find the down votes a big unnecessary...